# NSString without HTML markup

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsstring, strip

I have a JSON Data, and I would like to make this JSON Data into NSString without HTML markup.

Here is my JSON Data :

```
<p><strong style="font-size: 13px;">13th March</strong></p>
<p><span id="fbPhotoSnowliftCaption" class="fbPhotosPhotoCaption" tabindex="0" data-ft="{"tn":"K"}"><span class="hasCaption">Peak is solid 6ft + a bit wild but not a breath of wind around. Rossnowlagh will be the pick of the beaches. Very good surf forecast all weekend and into the middle of next week</span></span>.</p>
<p><span id="more-113"></span></p>
<p>High tide: 10:56, 3.2m    <span style="color: #ff0000;"> <a href="http://www.bundoransurfco.com/webcam/"><strong></strong></a></span></p>
<p>Low Tide: 16:32, 1.4m</p>
<p><b>3 day forecast to March 16th</b></p>
<p>Windy midweek but the surf is looking very good from Friday onward, right through the weekend.</p>
        <style type='text/css'>
```

I would like to get this kind of NSString :

```
13th March
Peak is solid 6ft + a bit wild but not a breath of wind around. Rossnowlagh will be the pick of the beaches. Very good surf forecast all weekend and into the middle of next week.
High tide: 10:56, 3.2m
Low Tide: 16:32, 1.4m
3 day forecast to March 16th
Windy midweek but the surf is looking very good from Friday onward, right through the weekend.
```

I've already test with **stripHtml**, but after using it, my NSString is just : `13th March`

Here is my code (the text of the report is always before `#gallery-1` so it's not that the problem... but with some html markup I think... (because with different markup it works!) :

```
NSString* stringBDD = [[dicoBDD objectForKey:@"post"] objectForKey:@"content"];
NSString *stringWithoutLiveWebcam = [stringBDD stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"CLICK HERE FOR LIVE PEAK WEBCAM" withString:@""];
NSString *stringReportFirstPart = [[stringWithoutLiveWebcam componentsSeparatedByString:@"#gallery-1"] firstObject];
NSString* stringWithoutHtml = [stringReportFirstPart stripHtml];
NSLog(@"stringWithoutHtml : %@", stringWithoutHtml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the HTML tags by using the regular expression: `</?[^>]*>`. Using `stringByReplactingMatchesInString` with the regex and an empty-string replacement, you can strip the tags out.

```
@interface NSString (HTML)
- (NSString *)stripTags;
@end

@implementation NSString (HTML)
- (NSString *)stripTags {
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"</?[^>]*>"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                           error:&error];
  if (error == nil) {
    return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:self
                                           options:0
                                             range:NSMakeRange(0, self.length)
                                      withTemplate:@""];
  } else {
    return self;
  }
}
@end
```